# Can I easily over-ride Django ORM 'iexact' to use LOWER() instead of UPPER()?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

**Using Django 1.3x.**

I currently have a very, very large and very, very active Postgres data set that has an important column indexed as `lower(column)`.

I just realized that some common queries were quite slow because the Django ORM is generating a query for the field as `blah = UPPER(column)` when I'm using `iexact` to match that field.

**Is there a simple way to force the ORM to use `lower()` instead, or do I need to drop into raw SQL for this one?**

Thanks!

[side question for the comments: Is there a good reason, overlooked, to have used `upper()` on the index, rather than `lower()`?]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interesting situation here. I'd never really stopped to think about it before. Seems like the use of `UPPER` for `iexact` searches was introduced back in [revision 8536](https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/8536), in response to [ticket 3575](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3575), nearly three years ago. Before that Django had been using `ILIKE` for these types of searches.

I looked through the backend code and the only thing I can find that points to any reason for `UPPER` vs `LOWER` seems to be that Oracle defaults to uppercase in its treatment of case-insensitive data. Since the others are agnostic, it seems Django decided to default to `UPPER` to cover all the bases.

The other impression I got from looking at the source code was that you're not going to get around using `UPPER`. It's literally all over the place and not just when actually querying the database. Python's `upper` string extension is used quite frequently as well.

I'd say your best bet is to simply create an index with `upper(column)` as well or instead of, and go have a drink.

Comment: Chris, Thanks for your answer! I also came across those tickets, but didn't see any major discussion on why it suddenly changed to `upper()`. Your insight about the Oracle bit is the most I've heard. This is a simple query, really, so I suppose I'll just use `.raw()` here. Thanks so much!

Comment: Postgres requires an index for UPPER to avoid table scans when using iexact, so note that anywhere you are using iexact on an indexed field, you now need to (manually) add an UPPER index on that field. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597986/how-can-i-create-a-case-insensitive-database-index-in-django for details

Answer (score 3):

Try [`.extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#extra) before going to `.raw()`

```
MyModel.objects.extra(where=["lower(mycol)=%s"], params=['foo'])
```